# update multiple data extension in real time

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript, dataextensions

we have a 3rd party tool which is sending us XML data using the rest api endpoints and it gets stored in the data extension, now, there are 10 more data extension which needs to be populated based on the xml file i received as xml. Is there a way to achieve this is real time? (as soon the xml file is sent to data extension it should parse the xml and store the data in different data extensions)

Comment: Are you able to change the code and endpoint on your 3rd party tool? The answer to this question would change the solution aspect.

Comment: i dont know about this at the moment, let say im able to change the code and the endpoint, then what would be the solution?

Comment: Can you please add your sample xml payload and also outline what part of xml needs to be inserted to other DEs?

Comment: can you give me your email id - XML payload is huge, i dont think it will fit here.

Comment: Please email it here brad.sapkota@gmail.com